# Changing model id to uuid in Rails using uuid-ossp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid, rails-migrations

I need to change the id of the existing model to uuid. I'm using this guide:

http://rny.io/rails/postgresql/2013/07/27/use-uuids-in-rails-4-with-postgresql.html

But no idea how to adapt the migration below to changing (not creating a new one):

```
 class CreateDocuments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :documents, id: :uuid  do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :author
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: See the [reference](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/) document

Comment: According to your guide , you need to put enable_uuid_ossp_extension migration at first place in your migration list, you need to  rename it . this works for me when i try it on my machine .

Answer (score 5):

Try This.

```
    class documents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :documents, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false

    change_table :documents do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE documents ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681599/rails-4-migrate-table-id-to-uuid)

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically handles `uuid`, so you just need to change `id` to `uuid`, set the column type (`uuid` for `PGSQL`, `string` for `MYSQL`) and repopulate the table with the new `uuid`.

In doing this myself, I've only ever changed the `id` column to `uuid` for Rails to populate it automatically.

```
$ rails g migration ChangeID

#db/migrate/change_id______.rb
class ChangeId < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      rename_column :documents, :id, :uuid
      change_column :documents, :uuid, :uuid #-> will only work for PGQL, will have to make it string for MYSQL
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will rename your `:id` column to `uuid`, assigning the respective column type to it.

And, yes, I've used `:uuid` before...

[image]

--

A good ref:

- http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/

Comment: I got this error after following your answer, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/186d053b87fec30fc4218692267e7dee. can you help me out

Comment: This answer is kind of out of date now, I'll leave a comment with updated code