# How do I change the column_type and delete the data in it currently with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Using Rails 4, I have a column (`page_id`), and I need to force it to remove *all* data that's currently in the database column (it's in dev, so I don't care about anything that database right now).

My migration looks like this:

`change_column :sections, :page_id, :uuid`

(I'm migrating away from integers for Pages)

How do I use `change_column` and delete all the data that's currently in my database? Or do I need to do a `remove_column` and then an `add_column` that's set up correctly?

Comment: I think you might be best suited with a `remove_column` and `add_column`. The `change_column` is useful to change `column_name` and `column_type`. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681599/rails-4-migrate-table-id-to-uuid

Answer (score 0):

Remove then add the column seems the best option. But you can change the column and then update all the records with something like Section.update_all({:uuid => nil})